# Sensory-motor pathway from visceral organs

Tags: human-physiology

Does anyone know is which nerves carries the transmission of sensory-motor impulses from the visceral organs? Is it splanchnic nerves?
There is conflicting evidence in the literature. On the one hand, many sources told that splanchnic nerves belong to the sympathetic nervous system. On the other hand, there is information that sensory-motor impulses from the visceral organs travel along the splanchnic nerves. And there is a slight contradiction, because sensory-motor impulses usually go not in to to the sympathetic trunk, but to the dorsal ganglia. But the splanchic nerves connect just with the sympathetic trunk, and not with the dorsal ganglia.

For example, in this study:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22209656

sensory transmission pathways have been found to go to the spinal cord through the dorsal ganglia, which, to my knowledge, are not associated with splanchic nerves.